# If Statement for Multiple Post Pages - Show/Hide - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, loops

I searched like hell, but didn't find nothing similar. I barely can think, and I am tired like hell also so I ask you for help. I created custom pagination for my new theme, the thing is that I am using dividers and pagination elements together with negative margin so I need to make a statement, * (which I do not know why it doesn't work this time) * that will test the post for **IF** more pages exist paginated form with links will be displayed, and if a post has only one page, paginated elements will not be displayed, and instead of them, simple divider will be displayed. It is simple statement with IF-ELSE-END.

Code sample:

Custom Pagination:

```
function crnizec_numerical_link_pages( $args = array () )
{
    $defaults = array(
        'before'      => ' <p>' . __( '')
    ,   'after'       => '</p> '
    ,   'link_before' => ''
    ,   'link_after'  => ''
    ,   'pagelink'    => '%'
    ,   'echo'        => 1
    // element for the current page
    ,   'highlight'   => 'n'
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $r = apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_args', $r );
    extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

    global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more, $pagenow;

    if ( ! $multipage )
    {
        return;
    }

    $output = $before;

    for ( $i = 1; $i < ( $numpages + 1 ); $i++ )
    {
        $j       = str_replace( '%', $i, $pagelink );
        $output .= ' ';

        if ( $i != $page || ( ! $more && 1 == $page ) )
        {
            $output .= _wp_link_page( $i ) . "{$link_before}{$j}{$link_after}</a>";
        }
        else
        {   // highlight the current page
            // not sure if we need $link_before and $link_after
            $output .= "<$highlight>{$link_before}{$j}{$link_after}</$highlight>";
        }
    }

    $echo and print $output . $after;
    return $output . $after;
}
```

CSS style:

```
.post-nav {
text-align: center;
margin-top: -37px;
margin-bottom: 17px;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
}

.post-nav a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    color: #727272;
}

.post-nav a:hover {
    background-color: #727272;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #727272;
}

.post-nav n {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #727272;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #eaeaea;
    border: 1px solid #727272;
    cursor: default;
}

.post-nav n:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
```

And this is the statemen which should trigger the function. I am trying to make it minimalistic as possible.

```
<div>   
<?php if (crnizec_numerical_link_pages()) : ?>
<div class="line-break"></div>

<div class="post-nav">
<?php crnizec_numerical_link_pages(); ?>
</div>

<?php else : ?>
<div class="line-break"></div>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The thing is very simple, when there is no more pages on single post, don't show function. Ofcourse the function will not be displayed, but it will remain in background which will cause the css with negative margin to become active or stay active in the background and cause ​overlap with other elements. And I don't want that. This is simpliest solution I used so far, at least I know of.

So I need just to check if single post has more pages, if does, then show function for page numbers with divider, if not, show divider. My statment works, but there is a problem, it generates one more page navigation for post pages, but without css styles, right under post text. And i do not want to have 2 page navigations for post pages. I am sorry, my english is bad, I hope someone will understand. Need to kill my eyes now.

Here is an image of the problem.

[image]

Comment: yeah, your function never returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I guess I needed just a few hours of sleep to force caffeine out of my brain. :)